# How to disable wi-fi by killing a process (in the Task Manager)

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

What is the best process to kill in the Task Manager to kill the current wi-fi connection.  Preferably something that can be restarted easily.  (With this info I can write an app to kill the wi-fi connection when a certain event happens.)

(Windows 8.)

Comment: What makes you think it's a killable process?

Comment: It should depend on the wireless chipset maker.

Comment: Although a driver is a program and a process  is a program too, they're not the same as pointed out by @MichaelKjörling

Comment: Couldn't you write a simple batch script using ipconfig to release your address? Do you need to kill wi-fi or any internet connection to the computer? Example: ipconfig /release "wireless connection 1"

Comment: In searching for an answer I've found some wi-fi manufacturers use killable processes.  I think my system is using Microsoft built-in stuff.   I could install a 3rd party wi-fi manager, which would be killable - but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 3):

Don't kill the process, disable the wifi device via batch or command line:

`devcon disable "hardware/DevId*"`

`devcon enable "hardware/DevId*"`

Get the devcon utility from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

More discussion from [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229918/device-enable-disable-script).

EDIT:

( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) has info on how to programmatically query the WIFI deviceID using the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class. Note there is also a `Disable` Method.

Comment: Easy and simple, works for me ty @Yorik

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need.  I need a PID I can kill.

Comment: @Jack9090 **WHY?**

Comment: @Jack9090 - Does not exist.

Comment: ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) has info on how to programmatically query the WIFI deviceID using the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class. Note there is also a `Disable` Method.